# Remove ribbon bar in MFC c++

Tags: c++, mfc, ribbon

I'm trying to remove the ribbon bar, but let stay the quick access tool bar and the icon orb, can anyone tell me if this is possible? and if yes how i can do this?

I try to hide it by calling the RemoveAllCategories function and then minimizing the ribbon, the problem is that the bar that holds the categories tabs stays visible and right clicking on it it always display the option "Minimize the ribbon", this is almost ok (if i managed to remove this option from the context menu) but what i'm asking if there is any proper way of removing the ribbon bar and all its dependencies, bug again let stay the orb and the quick access tool bar.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
m_wndRibbonBar.ToggleMimimizeState();
```